# Why can a program access the file on the shared drive?

Tags: windows-10

There is a program name "delivery agent" to deliver files over ftp.
When it tries to access a file on the shared path i get the error file not found but i could clearly see file exists on the shared path.

When i copy the file from shared path to my desktop it works just fine.

Comment: Which account does "delivery agent" run as?  Does that account have permission to the share, and to the files within that share?

Comment: How do i find that

Comment: Have you confirmed that the program actually supports using UNC paths (which is what I assume you mean by "shared path" ie: `\\server\sharedfolder`) when picking files?  Not all programs do.

Comment: yes its an UNC path and the program supports it because it was working on an old computer until it was replaced with the new one

Comment: "How do i find that" Which account is running which process is available in the Task Manager under the "Details" tab.  Share/file permissions for the shared folder will be in the usual place on the computer sharing the folder.

Comment: "it was working on an old computer until it was replaced with the new one"  you should include valuable information like that in your question. :)